# I have an issues with mutation query in graphql javascript

Tags: javascript, graphql

I try this type of mutation but I didn't get a proper response please help me to solve that.

```js
mutation: new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Mutation",
  fields: {
    createProduct: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(productType),
      args: {
        products: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(productInput) }
      },
      resolve: (_, products) => {
        let pro = products;
        console.log("pro", pro);

        return products.push(pro);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the intention you had with `return products.push(pro)`?? Can you describe in detail what you wanted to happen here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to keep the products in memory inside of an array of products. There are two things wrong in your code. First, the second argument of the resolver returns an object of arguments because a field can have multiple arguments. You can either destructure the arguments or use the normal object access syntax. Second, `Array.prototype.push` [returns the new lenght of the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). Therefore, you can't return the result of this call (your product type most likely expects a product as a root value). Return `product` instead. Also you are pushing into the argument. Maybe you have a name conflict there. I would recommend to use singular for arguments and variables that are not arrays, lists, or sets.

```js
let products = [];

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: _,
  mutation: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "Mutation",
    fields: {
      createProduct: {
        type: new GraphQLNonNull(productType),
        args: {
          product: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(productInput) }
        },
        resolve: (_, args) => {
          console.log("pro", args.product);

          products.push(args.product);
          return args.product;
        }
      }
    }
  }),
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. your answer is really helpful me and its solve my issues.Thank you